# Reuse logic to query data based on date filter

Tags: sql

I have logic in place to pull records based on date. For example i have to check if a record that appeared in a week has also occurred in next 14 days then that records need to be flagged. So basically i have put self join to get that record.

Now i have to pull record for 3 months and see if that record appeared again but logic will be same(in next 14 days), so ideally i have to change date filter in query for every week and get data, is there a way i can do it in same query and get full 3 months data

let me know if more clarification required.

Comment: add an example and sample code

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Vid product Date 
1111         x 22-Jan 
2222 y 26-Jan 
3333 z 27-Jan 
   
Vid product Date Flag
4444 x 11-Feb Yes
5555 z 15-Feb No

Comment: Added sample data, product x which occurred during week 22-28 Jan has occurred in within next 14 days so its flagged but other one is not. I am using Oracle